# Reading and printing out an ODS file in browser using OpenTBS PHP

Tags: php, opentbs

I'm trying to work with an .ods file using PHP. The file essentially looks like this:

```
[empty cell] | title1 | title2 | title3
18.12.2012   |   2.5  |    9.4 |    0.1
19.12.2012   |   4.5  |    1.23|    0.2
20.12.2012   |   12.4 |    21.1|    0.8
21.12.2012   |   0.5  |    11.0|    0.6
```

What I need is to read the numbers, get the sums of rows and columns, and generate .odt files based on the info I get from this file.
Multiple stackoverflow and other threads suggest that OpenTBS would be really sufficient for this purpose but I'm kind of new to the Template Engine concept and a little to PHP itself so I've been reading the docs for a several days and the only thing I seem to understand is how to merge and generate documents based on a template. 
But can I read the data from the template or some other file I load to OpenTBS and process it? I suppose if I can read the data I can put it out in a browser using an HTML template, for example. And if it's not too much trouble I would really like to see some code examples of doing that, thanks.
If OpenTBS cannot do that, what other library I should use for reading ODF(ODS) files?

Answer (score 0):

Despite a data reader is in the roadmap of OpenTBS, the current version (1.9.5) cannot extract the data of a spreadsheet. But it can retrieve the XML of a spreadsheet.

So you can read retrieve the XML of the spread sheet containing the data, have a piece of code for extracting the data, then merge the data with an ODS template.

```
// Initialize the TBS instance
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong; // new instance of TBS
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN); // load the OpenTBS plugin

// Retrieve xml from the source file
$TBS->LoadTemplate('data_to_extract.ods');
$xml = $TBS->Source;

// your code saving the data from $xml into $data
// ...

// Merge the data with the template
$TBS->LoadTemplate('template.ods');
$TBS->MergeBlock('d', $data);
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE, 'result.ods');
```

For extracting the data from the XML you can note that numeric values in cell are stored in the attribute *office:value* of the cell. Example :

```
      <table:table-cell office:value-type="float" office:value="2.4" calcext:value-type="float">
        <text:p>2.4000</text:p>
      </table:table-cell>
```

Date values in cell are stored in the attribute *office:date-value* of the cell. Example :

```
      <table:table-cell office:value-type="date" office:date-value="2016-03-02" calcext:value-type="date">
        <text:p>02/03/16</text:p>
      </table:table-cell>
```

Comment: Okay, I see. Is there any information on when OpenTBS will be able to do the extracting?

Comment: Sorry for multiple commenting, just missed the opportunity to edit my previous comment.
I see how that is possible to do the extracting myself but it seems like I may have some kind of problem with reading my .ods file. I used the LoadTemplate method and when I tried to echo the result string it printed out some gibberish with like it's the case of bad encoding. Is that possible to echo the string correctly? I've tried to use 'OPENTBS_ALREADY_XML' and the 'UTF8' one, echo with <pre> but no success there.

Comment: The inner XML content is not supposed to be readable in an HTML page. Simply ask your browser to display the source code of the page and you will get the XML.